# Configure Xbee in API Mode (Program Modem to AT Mode)

Tags: api, xbee

I have configured Xbee in API Mode.

PC : WIN XP SP3
XCTU : 5.3.8.6
Baud rate : 9600
COM Port : Serial COM1
"Test/Query" : OK

I am not able to Configure it with XCTU
Read/Write Modem : Failed to enter command mode
Error : Action Required Dialogue doesn't disappear.

I want to change modem configuration & Program it with AT Mode.

Can you please help ?

Regards,
Vijay

Comment: Hello Again, 

I have checked again with another Xbee Base Module. 
Test/Query is ok. 

XCTU shows COORDINATOR AT Version - 1020 & ROUTER AT Version - 1220  in Modem Config 

Reading Module parameters gives OK result in XCTU.  
But, doesn't show Modem Type,Function Set & Version. 

Writing any value gives error : Getting modem type....OK
Programming modem...Lost communication with modem
Write Parameters...Failed. 

Also, Terminal shows - Echo for any typed char. 

What can i check for communication in this 2 Xbee ?

Comment: Try first to check the (BD-baud rate) parameter in xbee, if it the same as your X-CTU Software (which you said it is 9600), then try again .

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have a different baudrate than 9600 on the module. Try using different baudrates on XCTU. If that doesn't work you can try the recovery procedure. The latest version of XCTU (Version: 6.1.1) automates the task for you.